# Moving directory without modifying timestamp

Tags: directory, timestamps, mv

I would like to move a directory from one location to another but when I do I can see that the timestamp gets changed. Is there any way to retain the timestamp as original?

Have looked at the man page of `mv` but couldn't find any existing options.

Answer (score 13):

Use `cp` as following, `mv` doesn't do.

```
cp -r -p /path/to/sourceDirectory /path/to/destination/
```

from man cp:

```
-p
    same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps
--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
    preserve the specified attributes (default: mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

then after copy done, delete the  *sourceDirectory*.

Comment: It will leave the original directory as-is which needs to be deleted too

Comment: Yes, this is what `cp` does, you need do a deletion after copy.

Comment: Yes. I am more like looking for a single line `mv` alternative if available.

Comment: there is no AFAIK, only option is using `rsync` with `--remove-source-files` option to delete  _files_ only but this will not delete directory itself, so you need do directory deletion too after that.

Comment: So `cp -r --preserve=all` is the best I can get?

Comment: `cp -rp SRC DEST && rm [-rf] SRC` *is* a single line.

Answer (score 4):

On linux, this works:

```
timestamp=$(stat -c %y foldername)
mv foldername new_foldername
touch -d "$timestamp" new_foldername
```

The `stat -c %y` command returns the modification date of the folder, in readable form. That value is retained and used with the command `touch -d "$timestamp"` to set the time of the new folder.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. May I recommend that you use the new recommended `$( ... )` style for command substitutions instead of backquotes, and not use all-uppercase-variable names unless they are environment variables?